# Pass shell environment variable as argument in npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to pass environment variables to npm scripts as arguments
with no success.

```
export ENVIRONMENT=test.proxy.json
npm run test
```

I'm trying to do something like this in package.json

```
npm run test --proxy-config-file $ENVIRONMENT
```

Comment: Have you tried `ENVIRONMENT=test npm run test` with in your package.json `*script* $ENVIRONMENT` ?

Comment: Actually, I tried exactly how @heldt did it, and it worked on my system (i.e. export first, then doing npm run).  Not sure why it's not working for him.  What OS and npm versions are you on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do this:

```
export ENVIRONMENT=test.proxy.json
npm run test
```

or this:

```
ENVIRONMENT=test.proxy.json npm run test
```

then you will pass the `"test.proxy.json"` string as a value of the environment variable named `ENVIRONMENT`.

If you want to pass arguments to npm scripts then you may need to use:

```
npm run test -- --proxy-config-file $ENVIRONMENT
```

Keep in mind that if you pass the argument to the npm script, it doesn't necessarily mean that it will be passed to other scripts that this script is executing. With environment variables it's the other way around - by default they should be passed from one script to the other but there is still no guarantee as the caller may decide what environment variables to pass, if any.

But it's hard to tell from your question what is your real problem here - the phrase "with no success" is too general to know what is the problem here.